# From a .side file to a GitLab CI/CD pipeline step?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-ide, continuous-integration

Is there a way to add a GitLab CI pipeline step that launches a Selenium test which is coded in a Selenium IDE file (.side) ?

Comment: Have you *tried* creating that step? What happened?

Comment: I'm not currently trying to do it, I don't even know how to add steps in a GitLab CI pipeline. But before I lose a lot of time trying to do it, I would like to make sure it is technically possible. If someone knows about a technical limitation that makes it impossible, I'd like to be aware soon enough.

Answer (score 2):

The new Selenium-IDE has a [command line runner](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/command-line-runner/) for `.side` files, based on nodejs.

I havent tried it myself on Gitlab, but if you can run it from the command line you should be able to run it in any CI/CD platform.

I guess the setup is similar to this: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/end_to_end_testing_webdriverio/

Where you change the script to: `selenium-side-runner yourproject.side`